# Keycloak: Admin-cli Add SMTP server details?

Tags: keycloak

In our keycloak we have written admin-cli command to make things smooth after keycloak bought up .We will create some basic Realm/user/group and other details from the help of admin-cli .

Now we want to add the SMTP server details through admin-cli . How can be achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok at last too many hit and try i found the solution . Here is the details how to add the SMTP server details via admin-cli

First Step Enable HTTPS(As in our case keycloak running on HTTPS)

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh config truststore --trustpass keycloak  /opt/keycloak/security/ssl/keycloak.jks
```

Second Step Login with client admin-cli

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh config credentials --server https://{{keycloak_server_IP}}:{{keycloak_port}}/auth --realm master --user admin --password admin --client admin-cli
```

If realm not created create it via this

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create realms -s realm=SURE -s enabled=true
```

and then run below command

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh update realms/CRUE_Realm -x -s 'smtpServer.host=Your Host Name' -s 'smtpServer.from=email@somemail.com' -s 'smtpServer.fromDisplayName=Mail Support' -s 'smtpServer.auth=false' -s 'smtpServer.ssl=false'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this command

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh update realms/CRUE_Realm -f - << EOF
{"smtpServer" : {
    "replyToDisplayName" : "...",
    "starttls" : "",
    "auth" : "true",
    "envelopeFrom" : "...",
    "ssl" : "true",
    "password" : "...",
    "port" : "...",
    "host" : "...",
    "replyTo" : "...",
    "from" : "...",
    "fromDisplayName" : "...",
    "user" : "..."
  }
}
EOF
```